# Find whole number solutions

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Sorry if this is a dupe or too basic, the similar questions seemed to have extra requisites tacked on. Background: Solving the [Cheryl's birthday riddle sequel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cheryl%27s_Birthday) maybe I'm on the right track, maybe not, though there might be some more elegant way to think about it. No hints please.

Is there a procedure to find all whole number solutions for

$$\sqrt{\frac{x^2}{16}-36}$$

I've found x = 24 (root) and x = 40 and want to find the next positive one, systematically. Preferably not by stacs* for the specific numbers up there but for something general like $\sqrt{\frac{x^2}{a}-b}$.

*smart tricks and coincidences

Comment: Presumably $x$ and $\sqrt{(x^2/16)-36}$ are both supposed to be integers?

Comment: You want $\sqrt{\frac{x^2}{a}-b} = y$ for some non-negative integer $y$. Hence $x^2/a = y^2 + b$. So $x^2 - ay^2 = ab$. If $a$ is a perfect square (which it is for your particular example), then you can factor the left-hand side using difference of two squares and equate each factor to factors of the right-hand side.

Comment: Im with you until the part 'factor the left hand side using the difference of two squares'. What two squares is this referring to? x^2 and a?

Comment: I'm just using the formula $A^2 - B^2 = (A+B)(A-B)$ with $A^2 = x^2$ and $B^2 = ay^2$.

Comment: For $x^2/16$ to be an integer $x$ needs to be divisible by four. So if $x=4a$ you have $\sqrt{a^2-36}.$ Without loss of generality $a$ is positive. Then $a^2-36$ is a bit less than $a^2$, so that square root must be $a-h$ for some positive integer $h$. In other words $$(a-h)^2=a^2-36\Leftrightarrow h^2-2ah=-36.$$
Implying $h(2a-h)=36$. So $h$ must be a factor of $36$. List all those, and then solve for $a$ from $(2a-h)=36/h$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what is known as a [Diophantine equation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiophantineEquation.html).

Your general case related to [Pell's equation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PellEquation.html) which is $x^2-Dy^2=\pm1$. For non-square number values of $D$ this has been shown to have solution related to the continuous fraction of $\sqrt{D}$. (If $D$ is a square it can be solved using more elementary techniques I'll demonstrate below.) The more [generalized form](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiophantineEquation2ndPowers.html) of $x^2-Dy^2=c$ has solutions for some situations but not all.

Seeing the link:

$$n=\sqrt{\frac{x^2}{a}-b}$$

$$n^2=\frac{x^2}{a}-b$$

$$ab=x^2-a\cdot n^2$$

So for some values of $a$ and $b$ this can be solved and for others it can't.

**Special Case**

If your $a$ is a perfect square, say $a=c^2$ then sub it in and rearrange to get:

$$bc^2=x^2-(cn)^2$$

$$bc^2=(x+cn)(x-cn)$$

So you need two numbers which multiply to give a total of $bc^2$. Find all factors of $bc^2$, say $d$ and $e$. You want them to both be divisible by $c$ and have the same parity (i.e. both even or both odd) after dividing by $c$ to avoid non-integer solutions because solving $x+cn=d$ and $x-cn=e$ gives $x=\frac{d+e}{2}$ and $n=\frac{d-e}{2c}$.

**Final Note**: For your specific situation of $\sqrt{\frac{x^2}{16}-36}$ you have found all the positive solutions. The negative values of $x=-24$ and $x=-40$ also work due to the squaring nature of the problem. This can be seen as follows:

$$16\cdot36=x^2-16n^2$$

$$4^2\cdot36=(x+4n)(x-4n)$$

Next look for all pairs of numbers which multiple to give $4^2\cdot36$ which also divide by 4 (which is why I've left the $4^2$ at the front). Going through all the possible combinations gives:

- $x+4n=4\cdot18$ and $x-4n=4\cdot2$ which gives $x=40$ and $n=8$
- $x+4n=4\cdot6$ and $x-4n=4\cdot6$ which gives $x=24$ and $n=0$
- $x+4n=4\cdot-2$ and $x-4n=4\cdot-18$ which gives $x=-40$ and $n=8$
- $x+4n=4\cdot-6$ and $x-4n=4\cdot-6$ which gives $x=-24$ and $n=0$

Note that all other choices for splitting up $4^2\cdot36$ gives non-integer answers. e.g. $x+4n=32$ and $x=18$ gives $x=25$ and $n=\frac{7}{4}$.

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer. Trying to apply it, is there an error, should it be (d-e)/2c?

And I think I'd appreciate a little pointer at the end, say i've done d = 36 and e = 16 in my case. I get n = 2.5 and x = 26, What Am I supposed to do from there?

Comment: Yes. Small plus/minus typo there. I'll expand my answer to show how it is used in your case.

Comment: I've also rephrased which pairs will lead to whole number solutions and which won't. The two numbers need to have the same parity after you divide them by the 4. I.e. 36/4=9 and 16/4=4 do not have the same parity hence the fractional answer.